# Set a field to be editable by list owners only

Tags: development

I have a list that has field A and field B that is set to ReadOnly by PowerShell. Now, these fields are ReadOnly for everyone. I would like these fields to be editable only for the list owners. Is there any PowerShell commands that will let these fields be editable only for the owners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it simply, no. SharePoint does not have a concept for column-level security, which is what you're asking for. Either you may contribute to a list/list item and all columns belonging to that list/list item, or you cannot.

The way people often accomplish this is by exposing the list in such a way that hides the columns on the New/Edit forms or by extracting the list away entirely (e.g. creating New/Edit forms in PowerApps) and selectively displaying fields as required.

This doesn't remove an individual's ability to go to the back end list and modify the data directly, including the column you don't want to modify it, but in my personal experience, abstracting/modifying the new/edit forms is usually "good enough".

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned by No SharePoint list can do this but There are two aspects You can take as a workaround. I am Assuming You have Access to PowerApps and MS-Flow

**Solution one: Using Custom Form**

You need to create a Custom Form for that specific List. The fields should not be read-Only
In your custom Form, You need to define Admin/Owner as Variable. If a none admin user whats to edit the form Make the field Disable or Hiden.

**Solution Two: Hide the field(column)**

This is a lot easier. 
Change that Read-only field to editable field(Let's call it Field B) and Add this to the views only accessible by Admin(owner)
then create a calculated column which reads from Field B. We call this Field C
Don't Let the User Create View or edit list setting(give this permission only to Owner/ Admin)
create custom form in Powerups/info Path without Field B

**Solution three: Using MS Flow**

In this aspect we let every user change the field But update the list only if the user is an admin/Owner
Change those fields to Read-Write Field
Enable version History on the list
Enable Append comment on the field
Create a flow which prevents the field from being updated if the user who changed it is not the owner. This flow updates the field with previous value if the user who changed it is not Owner